# /class/:id page doesn't show in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am developing React app and I have some problems while implementing routing.

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Layout>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />
        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/class/:id" component={Class} />
        <Route path="/class" component={Classes} exact={true} />
      </Layout>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

When I navigate home page on local , i.e  localhost:8000 , home page is displayed.
And when I click `class` link, browser navigates to `/class` and classes page is displayed.
And when I click specific class item , browser navigate to `/class/:class-id` and specific class detail page is displayed.

But when I manually type in `/class/:class-id` in browser, class detail page is not displayed.
When I inspect the browser,  `bundle.js` was referred to `localhost:8000/class/bundle.js`.
But `bundle.js` is referred to `localhost:8000/bundle.js`.
[image]

I am using webpack and here's webpack configuration.

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('interpolate-html-plugin');
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    // Here the application starts executing
    // and webpack starts bundling
    output: {
    // options related to how webpack emits results
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"), // string
      // the target directory for all output files
      // must be an absolute path (use the Node.js path module)
      filename: "bundle.js", // string,
      // the filename template for entry chunks,
      assetModuleFilename: "assets/[hash][ext][query]"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader" },
                    { loader: "less-loader" }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
                type: "asset/resource"
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html',
            favicon: './public/favicon.ico',
        }),
        new InterpolateHtmlPlugin({
            PUBLIC_URL: 'http://localhost:8000/public'
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        port: 8000,
        open: true
    },
    externals: {
        // global app config object
        config: JSON.stringify({
            apiUrl: 'http://localhost:4000'
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: [React-router URLs don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Comment: The short answer is that your server needs to be set up in a way that it serves static files from the root folder instead of serving a 404. So if your app will be deployed to an apache server for instance you can probably skip over the first answer and directly start with the [2nd one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40591955/5734311)

Comment: When I manually type `/class/:id` in address bar, when base URL is localhost:8000/class?
I want base URL to be localhost:8000 so that `bundle.js` can be referred to `localhost:8000/bundle.js`

This all are the issues related to server routing? not client side routing?

Comment: When your browser is at `http://localhost:8000/class/3` and finds `<script src="bundle.js">` it will try to load `http://localhost:8000/class/bundle.js`. It doesn't care about this being React router; it just does it's regular thing. So you need to make sure the server still serves the file instead of a 404.

Comment: So should I have to resolve this issue in nodejs server like Express?
Let me try that.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you have to resolve this server-side. With express it's really easy. Note that it ultimately depends on where you deploy the finished app.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution.

```
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html',
            favicon: './public/favicon.ico',
            publicPath: '/'
        }),
        new InterpolateHtmlPlugin({
            PUBLIC_URL: 'http://localhost:8000/public'
        })
    ]
```

I added `publicPath: '/'` to HtmlWebpackPlugin so that `bundle.js` can be referred to absolute path, not relative path.  `localhost:8000/bundle.js`
So it works perfect now.

On the other hand, I researched isomorphic application but found that its main benefits are to improve performance & SEO implementation.

This idea appeared  to improve performance & SEO implementation after modern JS frameworks which have client rendering ability.
Since Google announced and supported SEO regarding javascript, this idea lost enthusiast , but still be used for its benefits.

I am sure isomorphic and catch-all method can resolve my issue with perfect.
But for now, I prefer my current solution, it's simple.